# Will GCD Timer not work like NSTimer under some condition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer

As we all know, under `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`, NSTimer will not fire when the scrollView is scrolling. If we need the timer works, we should add it to `NSRunLoopCommonModes`.

Consider that,

```
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, aQueue);
dispatch_resume(timer); // Is the place for `dispatch_resume(timer);` appropriate? Or we should
always put it after `dispatch_source_set_event_handler`?

dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, ti * NSEC_PER_SEC, ti * 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
    if (anAction) anAction();
});
```

when I create timer based on GCD like above, will the timer be hang or ignored, in other words could not fire, under some condition? Or **it will run forever?**

Here's my thinking:

## What if the queue is suspended?

If it doesn't run on the queue, the timer will continue running regardless of the queue's status.

If it does run on the queue, the timer is suspended as well as the queue.

## Where does the timer run?

According to the doc, `dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, aQueue);` means :

> Creates a new dispatch source to monitor low-level system objects and
>   automatically submit a handler block to a dispatch queue in response
>   to events.

it says that we submit the event handler to the argument `dispatch_queue_t queue`, that is we will respond to the event on the queue. But **it doesn't mean the timer runs on the queue**.

Thanks :)

Comment: Timers don't really run.  For regular (NS)timers, there is code in the runloop handler that checks if any timers have expired.  I suspect that it's the same for GCD timers, though I don't know who's responsible for checking expiration.

Comment: By the way, the code for libdispatch is available.  You could check there, and probably get your answer.